# What exactly are they saying during a Sephardic lilililili?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, hearing

This Shabbat, there happened to be a Sephardic simcha at the shul. As is customary, the women did this *lilililili* thing while throwing candy.

But what exactly are they saying? It sounded  sort of like *lililili ish*, or perhaps even *lololololo ish* (no man?).

What is it, actually?

Comment: Please help tag.

Comment: Closely related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22326/3483

Comment: I don't think they're saying anything

Comment: What is it? It's called ululating, and it's a form of cheering (though sometimes can be used in singing, too)

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13980/759

Comment: This is just an example of general non-Jewish Middle Eastern ululation. Some Jews happen to do it too.

Answer (score 3):

The Midrash (Bereshit Rabbah 70:19) says that at Yaakov and Leah's "wedding," the member of the audience, who were of aware of Lavan's scheme, tried hinting to Yaakov - Ha Lea! Ha Lea! - Hi Leah! - "She's Leah"

> יט [כט, כב - כה] ויאסוף לבן את כל אנשי המקום ויעש משתה כינס כל אנשי מקומו אמר להם יודעים אתם שהיינו דחוקים למים וכיון שבא הצדיק הזה לכאן נתברכו המים אמרין ליה ומה אהני לך, אמר להון אין בעיין אתון אנא מרמי ביה ויהב ליה לאה דהוא רחים להדא רחל סגי, והוא עבד הכא גבכון שבעה שנין אוחרין, אמרין ליה עביד מה דהני לך, אמר להון הבו לי משכון דלית חד מנכון מפרסם ויהבון ליה משכונין ואזל ואייתי עליהון חמר משח וקופר, הוי למה נקרא שמו לבן הארמי שרימה באנשי מקומו, וכולי יומא הוו מכללין ביה וכיון דעל ברמשא אמר להון מה הוא כדין אמרין ליה את גמלת חסד בזכותך והיו מקלסין קודמוי ואמרין הא ליא הא ליא, היא לאה היא לאה, ברמשא אתון מעלתא וחפון בוציניא, אמר להן מהו כדין, אמרי ליה מה את סבור דאנן דכרין דכוותכון, וכל ההוא ליליא הוה צווח לה רחל והיא עניא ליה, בצפרא והנה היא לאה אמר לה מה רמייתא בת רמאה לאו בליליא הוה קרינא רחל ואת ענית לי, אמרה ליה אית ספר דלית ליה תלמידים לא כך היה צווח לך אבוך עשו ואת עני ליה, ויאמר אל לבן מה זאת עשית לי וגו', ויאמר לבן לא יעשה כן וגו', מלא שבוע זאת וגו', א"ר יעקב בר אחא מכאן שאין מערבין שמחה בשמחה אלא מלא שבוע זאת וגו'.

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is the source for all middle eastern and african ululation?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the ululation actually goes kililililil, which, according to my uncle (from a family of fluent Aramaic speakers, lishan didan dialect), comes from the word kililah, which has something to do with happiness.  I'm not sure of the exact word, though, so if any readers are aware of the exact word and translation in Hebrew or Aramaic, let me know in the comments, and I can update it accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Sam, and thanks for your answer!

Comment: [כלילא](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%90)?

Comment: "Klilah" which indeed is also a word most common in Aramaic lit. (Talmud, Zohar) isn't etymologically nor phonetically related to this ululation. No pun intended, but sounds like typical middle eastern folklore. If anything, it's probably related to the word *yelalah* (יללה, as in "והיללו כל שתי יין" Joel 1:5) which is itself probably just an onomatopoeia.